# Finding strat point when signal become perodic

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to find the `Mean` of `three` cycles after the signal become periodic and reach to steady state. I have a signal that is not periodic at the beginning but after some time it became periodic. I want to find the `Mean` of the next `three` cycles which each cycle has `five` points.

Now I did that by opening the plot and find the point where the signal become periodic then I enter that point to MATLAB, then I got the results. The program working fine but I have a big problem. I have `500,000` data records and its impossible to open each one and find the starting point where the signal become periodic. Is there any way that I can find starting point without opening the plot because each case has a different starting point where the signal become periodic?

I used below code now

```
close all,clear variables,clear all;
clc;
prompt = 'Enter Strating Point?';    
N= input(prompt);
Result=mean(mean(1,N:N+4)+mean(1,N+5:N+9)+mean(1,N+10:N+14));
```

[image]

I attached sample of data, Column one is the signal and column two is the time.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/27lebrp1lwnmm3l/AABIhN1tzUSJQjjED954Yvyka?dl=0

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: You could find the index for the first point where diff(y)>0 and use it as the starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full edit:

```
%inputs: time and y (the response), both same length vectors
ppc = 5; % points per cycle
A = zeros(ppc,1);
for i = 1:ppc
    A(i) = mean(y(i:ppc:length(y))); 
end
[~,b] = min(A);

possidx = (length(time)+b-ppc):-ppc:b; %idx of lowest points
lowlist = fliplr(y(possidx));% lowest points
for i = 2:length(lowlist) %start from behind
    se = std(lowlist(1:i))/sqrt(i); %calculate SE for all current points
    if se > 0.05 %depending on your filed you might wanna change it to a lower value
        periodstart = time(possidx(i-1)); %lowest point of first period
        break
    end 
end
```

What it does: the first loop finds which group of points is always at the bottom. So adjust ppc to 10 if you have 10 points per cycle. The points per cycle don't have to be exactly the same for each cycle if you have a lot of them, it should still be reasonably accurate.

Then we add from behind one by one these lowest points and calculate the standard error. Once it is greater than 0.05 we are outside of the periods.

I felt so free to use standard error because that is something i know and that makes sense in this situation. I set the threshold to 0.05 because it's standard in many fields, alter it if it is different in your field.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am not sure if that will work. I update the question with a new plot. Sometimes the first periodic is not the first cycle. So, the Mean and RMS of the signal must be the same for all periodic cycles if the signal is periodic. I mean the mean for the three cycles must be the same if the signal is periodic. Same for RMS. My second plot explains what I mean. Also, my data from experiments sometimes are noisy. I am finding the mean when the periodic cycle reaches to steady state. That's why I referred that Mean and RMS must be the same for the next three cycles.

Comment: I see. This makes the problem a lot more complicated but also more interesting. Does each cycle have strictly 5 points?

Comment: Thank you so much. For each experiment, I have 500,000 date records and I am changing the number of points in the cycle each experiment. So, for the first one is 5, then for the next 500,000 record is 10. So, it's fixed for each 500,000 records. This is the beginning then when I will go to a turbulent number of points for each cycle will be different.

Comment: Do you have any information about the frequency of perodic signal? Is it the same for all data? If yes, sliding window FFT could be a nice solution.

Comment: @ Amritbir Singh Gill. Thank you so much. Unfortunately no I do not. If I have FFT will be nice.

Comment: Another solution: If the signal is non perodic only at the beginning, You can start taking mean from the end.

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes that will not work especially in turbulent flow.

Comment: i think the problem is so complicated that you have to come up with your own strategy on how to solve it. You just know a lot better how your data behaves than we do. We then can help you implement it.

Comment: You can also have a look at discrete wavelet transform to eliminate the decaying dc component at the beginning and find the first sample where higher frequencies appear.
I can post some code in an answer if you think it could work.

Comment: @Leander Moesinger. Thank you.  periodstart = time(possidx(i-1)); %lowest point if first period. You mean this will be the %lowest point for the first period. then I have to find the Mean for the next three cycles because I want to find the Mean for the first three cycles after the signal become periodic.

Comment: Exactly - sorry for typo.

Comment: @Leander Moesinger. Thank you. You are assuming that the signal will be always periodic at the end. That's why you start from behind and then you find the error for one, two,...etc lowest points. and if the error is greater than a specific number then this will be the first point. I do think that. Am I correct? However, if the signal is not periodic at the end then this will fail. Am I correct?

Comment: Yep, then it fails, sorry if it's not useful

Comment: @Leander Moesinger. No, it's very useful for part of experiments. and thank you again!I was trying to understand the code.